# How to get the name of the files excluded from the build in an Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm doing an Eclipse plugin and I need to get the list of all the files excluded from the build.
Do you know how to do that ?
(For example, to get the list of Include Paths, I used the ICSettingEntry interface)

Thank you for your help,

Chloé

Comment: I think a bit more context is needed.
Which kind of project is it (java, C, Eclipse plugin, go, web, ...)? Which kind of build (Maven, Gradle, ant, other)?

Comment: Hi ! I'm trying to get the list of excluded files from a C project via a cdt API and I'm not using any building tool for my plugin, just Eclipse for committers.